# Flutter - Trying to get the scaffold of a widget context from reducer

Tags: android, ios, mobile, dart, flutter

I am hitting a wall since I am trying use the context (to call a snackbar when the async action is done) of a widget from a reducer.

I have tried using GlobalKey, but when I get such key and I try to use the context of it to call the widget Scaffold it throws an error which says there is no Scaffold for such context, when there is infact.

Sadly I cannot provide the code because is for a customer and the code cannot be shown, but I can provide you with the details if it is needed.

The snackbar/toast itself is not that important, but if the context of a widget 
cannot be get from the reducer would be and important issue in the future.

Thanks

EDIT:
Here is a reproduce of the code as @Günter Zöchbauer has suggested:

-keys file

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class Keys {

  static final GlobalKey<MyWidgetState> myWidgetStateKey = new 
   GlobalKey<MyWidgetState>();
}
```

-Widget file

```
import 'package:myapp/keys.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_redux/flutter_redux.dart';

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget{

 @override
 MyPageState createState()=>new MyPageState();
}

class MyPageState extends State<MyPage>{

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext conext){

   return new Scaffold(
     key: Keys.myWidgetStateKey,
     appBar:new AppBar(
       title:new Text("My app bar")
     ),
     body: new Text("My app body")
   );
  }
 }
```

-Reducer file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:casinoadmiralapp/appState.dart';
import 'package:casinoadmiralapp/actions.dart';
import 'package:casinoadmiralapp/keys.dart';

AppState reducer(AppState state,action){

  BuildContext context = Keys.myWidgetStateKey.currentContext;

  if(action is TheAction){

   Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
    new SnackBar(
      content:new Text("You have done an action"),
      action: new SnackBarAction(
        label: "UNDO",
        onPressed: () => Scaffold.of( context ).hideCurrentSnackBar(),
      ),
    )
   );

  }
}
```

Comment: "Sadly I cannot provide the code because is for a customer" I can't imagine that to be the case. Nobody would bother to look at concrete project code anyway. What is required is a minimal reproduction. Creating such would probably be a great idea anyway because it most likely would reveal the bug in your code automatically.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbaue I have provided an small example. I hope it may help.

Answer (score 2):

I little-bit understand your problem. you are getting problem to show snack toast on view so I have share code to implementing snack bar.

```
class AprovedScreenState extends State<AprovedScreen> {
 BuildContext buildContext;
 final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
void navigationPage() {
 key.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
  content: new Text("Sending Message"),
));
```

write key code in scaffold method like below:

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
buildContext = context;
return new Scaffold(
  key: key,
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I am trying to use the global key from my reducer in order to show the snackbar/toast when an async action is executed.

Comment: Actually I think it's quite a bad idea to access the view from a reducer. The reducer should just update the store. The view should subscribe to store changes and then update the view accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I decided to follow @Günter Zöchbauer advice and to put the Scaffold into a store conector so when the store is updated I check the value of the store and due that changing the page.